# Import dynamic chunks into global namespace

Tags: webpack

For statically used modules  libraryTarget: "window" works great, but it doesn't using dynamic import(). There's nothing I could find for a parameter like this for chunks. In order to make dynamic imports global I had to resort to 
 Object.assign(window,await import("./CaseAccountScripts")); but it's ugly. I want to call await import(module) and populate global namespace with contained functions automatically, but it seems like there's no parameter for this.

Comment: You right, there is no parameter for this. Why do you need to populate window?

Comment: What I'm doing is sprinkling some modern goodness onto legacy devexpress app, and those will only work with global functions... :(